# Hover style remains when DIV is moved from under the cursor in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I've got [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ByEzV/1/)

Move the mouse over one of the "stacked" elements - hovered item changes it's color to dark
Click on an item - it is moving to the top of the stack.

In IE8 it is still "hovered" (dark background) but it is not under the mouse cursor now!

Comment: Since this bug wouldn't be possible without js, is using js for the hover effect acceptable solution?

Comment: He's not using js for the hover.

Comment: This issue exists in IE9 as well, however it appears to be resolved in IE10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cloning the element instead of moving the original. With the original you're taking the element in it's current state in the DOM and placing it in its new position and it appears IE is not repainting the element when this happens, or resetting its state until you mouseover again.

By cloning it, you're forcing IE to create a new element and since it wasn't on the page, can't have the hover state applied to it. Then just prepend into the container, remove the original, and you're done.

```
$(".elem").on('click', function(){
    $(this).clone(true).prependTo('#container');
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/y8PCc/1/

Credit to Dmitry from his answer here: [Internet Explorer :hover state becomes sticky when the target DOM element is moved in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891761/internet-explorer-hover-state-becomes-sticky-when-the-target-dom-element-is-mov)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class instead of a pseudo-class and remove it after moving

```
$(".elem")
    .hover(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("elem-hover", e.type == "mouseenter");
    })
    .click(function(){
        $(".elem:first").before(this)                    
        $(this).removeClass("elem-hover")
    })
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/ByEzV/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you change your jQuery to this it should work in ie8.

```
$(".elem").click(function(){
$(".elem:first").before(this);
$(this).css('background', '#fff').css('color', '#000');
})​
```

Comment: Bad solution, cause' if I change style I need to change code.