# IE8: Removing a node during CSS hover causes hover state to stick

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet Explorer :hover state becomes sticky when the target DOM element is moved in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891761/internet-explorer-hover-state-becomes-sticky-when-the-target-dom-element-is-mov)

I'm working on a system where rows can be dynamically added to a table by using a moving popup menu attached to the table row. This menu has options - "add row above", "add row below" and "remove row", and each option is styled to have a css-hover background colour effect. There is a button to show the menu, and when the mouse is moved over a different row, the button moves with it.

Internet Explorer 8 seems to have a problem with removing an element from the DOM while it's CSS hover effect is active. Doing so causes the hover state to stick, so the next time I open the menu, it's still highlighting the last option that was selected. The hover state is reset to normal when the mouse is moved over it and back out again.

This problem only began occurring after I changed my code - previously I was not removing the menu from the row prior to insertion, but I now remove and then reattach it. I need to do it this way because there will be situations where the menu must be removed from the DOM (e.g. when the last row of the table is removed).

Is this known behaviour?

```
BulkUpdateTable.prototype.addRow = function (isBefore) {
    var sourceRow = this.rowMod.parentNode.parentNode; // rowMod > td > tr
    sourceRow.firstChild.removeChild(this.rowMod); // Remove menu
    var newRow = sourceRow.cloneNode(true);
    var newRowFirstCell = newRow.firstChild;

    var origTableBody = sourceRow.parentNode;
    var tableBodyCopy = origTableBody.cloneNode(true); // Create in-memory copy of table body (allows for efficient editing without repeated redraws)
    var sourceRowCopy = tableBodyCopy.childNodes[getNodeIndexInParent(sourceRow)]; // Find corresponding row in copied table
    tableBodyCopy.insertBefore(newRow, isBefore ? sourceRowCopy : sourceRowCopy.nextSibling);
    this.incrementIdsFromNode(isBefore ? sourceRowCopy : newRow);
    origTableBody.parentNode.replaceChild(tableBodyCopy, origTableBody); // Replace table with updated copy. Note: Source nodes, event.srcElement, etc are no longer part of document

    this.rowModMenu.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Dismiss menu
}
```

Comment: Why are you using such a complicated script? Why can't you use a library like jQuery?

Comment: Well jQuery would make the DOM manipulation easier but I don't think it implements the core functionality of what I'm doing

Comment: What is it you want to do? It can do it in a rather easier way, do you want the jQuery version?

Comment: Turns out the problem is already addressed here. It's an IE bug.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891761/internet-explorer-hover-state-becomes-sticky-when-the-target-dom-element-is-mov
Voting to close